# Contact form returns a 404 error

Tags: error, 404

I have a contact form on my website (https://www.clay-and-paint.com). Before it works normally, I received emails from customers but now (I have an https) it doesn't work anymore.

I have a 404 error.

My code on my CMS page contact is:

```
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
```

My code on my form.phml is:

```
<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?></div>
<div class="page-title">
    <h1><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Contact Us') ?></h1>
</div>
<?php
   $url = Mage::getUrl();
   if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']))
   {
    $url = str_replace ('http://', 'https://', $url);
   }
?>
<form action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <h2 class="legend"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Contact Information') ?></h2>
        <ul class="form-list">
...
<div class="buttons-set">
        <p class="required"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
        <input type="text" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" style="display:none !important;" />
        <button type="submit" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?></span></span></button>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var contactForm = new VarienForm('contactForm', true);
//]]>
</script>
```

For the

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('contacts/index/post', array('_secure'=>true)) ?>
```

or:

```
<form action="https://www.clay-and-paint.com/index.php/contacts/index/post/" id="contactForm" method="post">
```

But it always returns me an 404 error.

Thank for your help.

Warui

PROBLEM SOLVED! I've made a mistake on my config.xml.

Comment: Can you access `yoursite.com/index.php/contacts`? That's where default Magento contact form is.

Comment: Hello Marius, sorry :/ Yes I have access to my index.php/contacts and I can fill my contact form (name, adress, comment...) and when I push on the SUBMIT button I arrive on a 404 error page.      You can see here my page when i push submit button (http://www.clay-and-paint.com/contacts/index/post)

Comment: ave you double checked the secure url setting in the system configuration? When exactly did the issue arise?

Comment: On my system configuration, I have on INTERNET: for unsecure website: http://www.clay-and-paint.com/ and for secure website: https://www.clay-and-paint.com/. Before I put the SSL certificate my contact form works. But I didn't tried it since a long time, I don't know if is the SSL the problem.

Comment: secure: https : // www . clay-and-paint . com and unsecure: http : // www . clay-and-paint . com. I put space because you see the same adress on my comment ;)